# Setting Radio Button property from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to Windows From design and using Visual Studio 2017 edition. I have two radio buttons in mainFrom. I have Radio-button Check_changed event handler in mainform for both radio buttons like below.

```
    private void radioButtonSystem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButtonSystem.Checked == true)
        {
            Address = 192;            
            ToAddress = 150;          
        }
     }
```

By default i set both radio buttons checked to false in properties at design time.

I have a serial port class where i am receiving data from hardware, based on incoming data I have to set one of the radio buttons to true. main window class own the instance of the serial port class

I would like to know how to Access radio buttons and change status checked to true from serial class??

Thank you in advance.

Edited:

I have tried like this but still i dont see radiobutton is checked. Can some one suggest me what might be wrong i am doing.
I have code in serial class like this.

```
    void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       //retrieve number of bytes in the buffer
        int bytes = configcomPort.BytesToRead;
        //create a byte array to hold the awaiting data
        byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
        //read the data and store it
        configcomPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
        if(comBuffer[0] == 6 && comBuffer.Length > 5)
        {
            Software.FrmMain frmMain = new Software.FrmMain();
            if (comBuffer[3] == 100) frmMain.radioButtonSystem.Checked = true;
        }
     }
```

It is raising the RadioButton_checkChanged event in mainfrom but it was not showing as it is set to true and selected in the application. it is showing like below

[image]

It should show as system one set to true and selected but i dont see that.

Comment: Like `radioButtonSystem.Checked = true`?

Comment: Decide. Is your problem about WPF or WinForms (**edit** your question and remove the wrong tag)? It cannot/should not be about both, because both UI frameworks are substantially different from each other...

Comment: Does the main window class own the instance of the serial port class? If not, who does? It's as if you're asking "how do I get from my house to the gas station", but we don't know the street address of either one; maybe you live in Sheboygan, Wisconsin and the gas station you have in mind is in Fort Lauderdale. (EDIT: Sheboygan isn't in Michigan)

Comment: @EdPlunkett  yes,main window class own the instance of the serial port class.

Comment: I would give the serial port class one or more events that it raises when the incoming data changes in ways that matter. Then the main window would attach handlers to those events, and set its own checkboxes accordingly. If you didn't write the serial port class, subclass it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try invalidating the mainform the other form like

```
... 
Software.FrmMain frmMain = new Software.FrmMain();
if (comBuffer[3] == 100){
   frmMain.radioButtonSystem.Checked = true;
   frmMain.Invalidate(true);
};
```

This will invalidate all the children of your main form, as well as your radio buttons.

An other way would be to pass the main form as a parameter to your other Form when you call it. Then you would edit the radio buttons on the already created Form. By creating a new instance you would edit a not displayed instance.
like:

```
TestForm form = new TestForm(this);
form.Show();
```

And in your forms constructor you would have

```
public TestForm(MainForm _main){
   ...
}
```

Then you would set the radioButtons as a child of _main checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to do this:

1) You can set radiobuttons properties Modifiers:public and you can reach this radiobutton from your serial port class like

```
Form1.radiobutton1.checked = true
```

2) You can declare private value on mainform and create getter & setter methods to reach this variable with initiliaze form object. You can use a timer for check this variable status, if true it makes radiobutton checked. Or directly use public variable in form1.

3) Use backgroundworker to listen serial port class variable, if variable changes, change radiobutton status in mainform directly.

Comment: I have set radiobuttons properties Modifiers:public; i have created instance for main in serial class and set the property checked to true when i receive data and conditions met. It is raising the radiobutton_checkchanged event in mainfrom but it was not showing in the main from as selected. I am setting it to true and i can see it is true while debugging but i am not able to understand why it was not showing as selected in mainfrom. any thoughts??